# Sending message every 15 minutes in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I need to make my telegram bot, send django model object to chat every 15 minutes.

Any builtins functions in python-telegram-bot to send message every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`run_repeating()`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating) method for that:

```py
def callback_foo(callback_context):
   pass  # send message here


def scheduling_method(context_or_dispatcher):
    # context or dispatcher, depending on what you have available
    job_queue = context_or_dispatcher.job_queue  
    job_queue.run_repeating(
        callback=callback_foo, interval=60 * 15,
    )
```

This can help to do any periodic calls for your Telegram Bot. There are even shortcuts to run methods you need on daily or monthly basis.

Comment: with `scheduling_method()` where does `context` come from, and if `callback_foo` needs to use the `update` parameter how does that work?

Comment: @fulvio sorry my fault. Forgot to add argument to `scheduling_method`. The main goal is to find `job_queue`, which under the hood has access to everything (context, dispatcher, etc.)

Comment: @fulvio if I'm not mistaken, `update` actually has `context` attribute.